# Does Maybe MonadPlus Parsers need to be in certain order?

Tags: haskell, monadplus

Im working through the exercises on [wikibooks/haskell](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell) and there is an exercise in the [MonadPlus-chapter](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/MonadPlus) that wants you to write this hexChar function. My function works as shown below, but the thing is that when I try to switch the 2 helper parsers (digitParse and alphaParse) around the function ceases to work properly. If I switch them around I can only parse digits and not alphabetic chars anymore.

Why is this so?

```
char :: Char -> String -> Maybe (Char, String)
char c s = do
    let (c':s') = s
    if c == c' then Just (c, s') else Nothing

digit :: Int -> String -> Maybe Int
digit i s | i > 9 || i < 0 = Nothing
        | otherwise      = do
    let (c:_) = s
    if read [c] == i then Just i else Nothing

hexChar :: String -> Maybe (Char, String)
hexChar s = alphaParse s `mplus` digitParse s -- cannot switch these to parsers around!!
    where alphaParse s = msum $ map ($ s) (map char (['a'..'f'] ++ ['A'..'F']))
          digitParse s = do let (c':s') = s
                            x <- msum $ map ($ s) (map digit [0..9])
                            return (intToDigit x, s')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if read [c] == i then Just i else Nothing
```

The marked code has a flaw. You're using `Int`'s `Read` instance, e.g. `read :: String -> Int`. But if it's not possible to parse `[c]` as an int (e.g. `"a"`), `read` will throw an exception:

```
> digit 1 "doesnt start with a digit"
*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
> -- other example
> (read :: String -> Int) "a"
*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
```

Instead, go the other way:

```
if [c] == show i then Just i else Nothing
```

This will always works, since `show` won't fail (not counting cases where bottom is involved).

Comment: Alternatively, there's the function `readMaybe` which returns a `Read a => Maybe a` that I like to use a lot since it lives within the `Maybe` monad.